# What should I pack behind a cast iron fireplace?

Tags: fireplace, chimney

I have a cast iron open fireplace which is (loosely) attached to the chimney breast in my living room by the mantle piece.  There is a small but significant gap behind it where the bricks have been hacked out so it will fit.  What should I fill this gap with?  Currently any soot which forms can fall down behind the fireplace.

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Answer (score 1):

a picture would help, but i sense that no matter what i will recommend you to [use cob](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7H-ziKVLWY&feature=related) - that is, building with earth. i didn't understood exactly what gap you need to fill but cob can fill everything, it's cheap (cost nothing!) it's fixable, and it can stand the heat (with guaranty - in the past i have built some ovens with it).